# How to call 2 different forms in HTML by using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a web page consisting both Sign Up and Log In forms. How do I mention/work with only one form (say LogIn form) in Javascript without calling the Sign Up page since both of them are in  in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide one feature at a time by using DOM elements, for example:

```
var loginContainerElement = document.getElementById("div_loginContainer");
loginContainerElement.style.display = "none";
```

At the same time you can show another display by:

```
loginContainerElement.style.display = "block";
```

[Source](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use hide() and show() like this :

```
//Show login hide sign up
$("#divLogin").show();
$("#divSignup").hide();

//Hide login Show sign up
$("#divLogin").hide();
$("#divSignup").show();
```